# How to get session time out message using Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I want to get the session time out message when the session expires.Below is my **spring-security.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/LogOut"/>
    <form-login login-page="/Login" username-parameter="Name" password-parameter="Pwd"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/?timeout=true">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/Timeout?timeout=true" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

According to my knowledge using above code when the session expired it should redirect to `/?timeout=true OR /Timeout?timeout=true`. And on logout it should go to `/`. But in my case on logout also its redirecting to `invalid-session-url` so I am always getting timeout true for both normal logout and session timeout.

Please help me to differentiate this.

**UPDATE**

`/logout` request contains

```
session = request.getSession();
session.invalidate();
session = null;
```

Comment: `invalid-session-url` trigger when you are not invalidate session properly,can you show how you invalidate session?

Comment: In your web.xml what is the default page specified on application startup?

Comment: I have not specified anything..for "/" url i have loaded login page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Solved it! by writing a filter instead depending on Spring-security.

If any one is interested they can use the below code :-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class FilterToGetTimeOut extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {
        try {
            if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/") || request.getRequestURI().equals("/Login/")){
                if(request.getSession().getAttribute("login") != null && (Boolean)request.getSession().getAttribute("login") == true){
                    response.sendRedirect(URL);     //After login page
                }
            } else if(request.getSession().getAttribute("login") == null && !request.getRequestURI().equals("/LogOut")){
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/?timeout=true");   //If timeout is true send session timeout error message to JSP
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log Exception

        }
    }
}
```

Add this filter in `web.xml`.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>FilterToGetTimeOut </filter-name> 
        <filter-class>package.FilterToGetTimeOut </filter-class> 
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>FilterToGetTimeOut</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
```

So now session also invalidates and I can handle the session timeout too.

Comment: What is the var URL in the 'After login page' snippet?

Comment: I dont understand What does this line do? response.sendRedirect(URL)

Comment: that will load the URL whichever you will mention....it will redirect.....  `response.sendRedirect("/errorLogin");` it will go to `http:localhost:xxx/xxxx/errorLogin`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to logout using this:

```
HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        if(session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        }
```

Comment: i tried by your answer, not able to get the session timeout always

Comment: `expired-url` is for session expired which mean if app detect user with more than `max-sessions` which in this case more than 1 session,then spring will redirect to `expired-url`. My answer is to make sure your logout doesnt go to `invalid-session-url`. If you want to make timeout that automatically log user out after certain time,you can use jquery.

Comment: Actually on logout if i remove session.invalidate also it is going to same

Comment: Sorry forgot one thing,If you want to use my answer, you need to remove <logout> in spring-security.xml. Can you tell how you want your system run?

Comment: On logout SpringContext should clear,session should be null and on session time out error message should come.

Comment: Is there any way to write filter for my spec

Comment: Yup,you're not using csrf,but by default,spring security will create one for you if you not disable csrf. Spring security is one type of filter. Please go through [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/) first

Answer (score 0):

In your case what happens is  when a user logout, the session is first invalidated then session management will get trigger. When session management come in, and found out the session has already gone, then sessionTimeout page will be redirect. So it will be better to set the invalidate-session of logout tag as false.

```
<logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="false" logout-url="/LogOut"/>
```

Comment: upon mentioning invalidate-session='false' also for logout its redirecting to invalidate-url

Answer (score 0):

Please define request mapping for logout-success url in your controller and from there redirect to home page.  for example replace your mapping as below

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<logout logout-success-url="/logoutSucess" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/LogOut"/>
<form-login login-page="/Login" username-parameter="Name" password-parameter="Pwd"/>
<session-management invalid-session-url="/?timeout=true">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/Timeout?timeout=true" />
</session-management>
```

define this /logoutSucess in controller with @RequestMapping(value="/logoutSucess" method=RequestMethod.GET)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, like

1. If you logged in with some user say zzzz
2. You closed the browser
3. Again you are trying to login with same user zzzz
4. It failed to login with message for maximum session exceeded

The code I have on my spring security file is:

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/?timeout=true">
<concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/logout?timeout" />
```

I solved this issue by adding the session timeout entry in web.xml file.
I put the session timeout value as 5 min, build the application and deployed.
Its working fine.

Might be this will help someone.

Thanks,
Atul