# Handle timeout with SpringSecurity

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, timeout, logout

We are using Spring Security to secure a web app and we would like to log the login/logout/timeout events.

Please let me explain the implementation so far:

1. Handling LogOut:

We use java config and login/logout works ok, we catch the logout event and session details like username with a logoutSuccessHandler(). However, this only works when clicking the logout link but not when the timeout happens.

In the configuration class:

```
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll() 
       .and().logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler);
```

and the handler definition:

```
@Component
public class LogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (authentication != null) {
            System.out.println("This user is closing the session: " + authentication.getName());
        }
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

So far so good with login and logout, when we click the logout link we are able to intercept the event and print the user name. Lets see the timeout configuration...

2. Handling Timeouts

To achieve session expiring by timeouts we configure it in a listener attached to the ServletContext:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("session created");
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(15);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
       System.out.println("session destroyed");
    }
}
```

Then in the Initializer:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
}
```

With the code above we are able to intercept the timeout in the sessionDestroyed() method but at this point the HttpSessionEvent has nothing to do with the spring session at all (for example, not able to access user name).

I am sure we are missing something to tie the HttpSession to Spring. It seems to me that our configuration for session expiring has nothing to do with Spring.

Having said this, there are some questions I have:

1. Is there a better way to handle sessions (session timeouts for example) with Spring so we do not have to create a listener in the ServletContext?
2. How can we do to intercept the timeout and be able to print the user details something similar to "Authentication.getName()"?

Please any advise or recommended lecture is more than welcome!

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708580/how-to-get-session-time-out-message-using-spring-security...

Comment: Register the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` which fires a spring event on session creation and destruction. No need to mess around with that yourself. You can use those to mark the start and end of a session. When you receive a `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` you can calculate if it was a timeout or a general logout.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternative ways:

1) Use jquery timeout,you can find more free plugin for using with your web. (ex:[jquery idle timeout](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout))

2) Once,I also struggle for this issue,one of the workaround I been doing is by using sandbox iframe. Display all the details in the page and at the end of the page,put the iframe that have link to logout the user.

That's some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to get the username on a timeout:

```
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession httpSession = event.getSession();
    long lastAccessedTime = httpSession.getLastAccessedTime();
    int maxInactiveTime = httpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000; //millis
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((currentTime - lastAccessedTime) >= maxInactiveTime ){
        //if is a timeout
            SessionInformation i = sessionRegistry().getSessionInformation(event.getSession().getId());
            String username = ((User) i.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        }
    }
```

In the same file i have

```
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```