# Invalidate session spring security

Tags: java, jsf-2, spring-security

My web application uses spring security to authenticate user on login. I also have concurrency control to avoid user to login twice on different machine. This is working fine but my problem is that:
 If user is login on a machine, then close the browser. And he reopen the web app , try to login again he gets the following msg 'Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded' . I want to invalidate the session on browser closed. How can I do this?

Spring-security.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <beans xmlns="http://.   www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/.    XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/.  spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" />

  <security:http auto-config="false"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
        <security:form-login
              authentication-failure-handler-ref="fail"
              authentication-success-handler-ref="success" login-page="/car/login.xhtml"
              default-target-url="/jsf/car/home.xhtml" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
              logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" success-handler-ref="customLogoutHandler" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <security:session-management>
              <security:concurrency-control
                    max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsf/**"
              access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/run**"
              access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.xhtml"
              access="permitAll" />
  </security:http>

  <bean id="success" class="com.car.LoginSuccess" />

  <bean id="fail" class="com.car.LoginFailed">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/?login_error=true" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />

  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
              user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
              <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"
                    hash="sha" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>
```

```
    public class FilterToGetTimeOut extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {
    try {
        if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/") || request.getRequestURI().equals("/car/login.xhtml")){
            if(request.getSession().getAttribute("login") != null && (Boolean)request.getSession().getAttribute("login") == true){
                response.sendRedirect("/jsf/car/home.xhtml");     //After login page
            }
        } else if(request.getSession().getAttribute("login") == null && !request.getRequestURI().equals("/j_spring_security_logout")){
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/?timeout=true");   //If timeout is true send session timeout error message to JSP
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log Exception

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show spring-security.xml?

Comment: See edited post. The concurrency control works well. I don't think the close browser issue is related to the xml file.

Comment: <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/">
              <security:concurrency-control
                    max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>...try it..add invalid-session-url

Comment: I try it n Still the same ...

Comment: <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="login?timeout=true" />...try this it should work

Comment: This doesnot work. I want to able to relogin again if user accidentally closed on browser.

Comment: Than you should write a filter...check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708580/how-to-get-session-time-out-message-using-spring-security

Comment: Do you know how to add this filter in web.xml?

Comment: Yes ofcourse..check that link again

Comment: ok I try to implement it and now When I open my web app in browser, it gives me this:
This webpage has a redirect loop.

Comment: May be you are missing in if condition..so its going to infinite loop...show me the condition you have added

Comment: @Sam see edited post

Comment: For which request it is redirecting to infinite loop? ....'/' or any other?? and when you are storing login attribute to session

Answer (score 12):

Add below code for **`"/"`**(first page) request and **`logout`** request.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadApp(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        if(session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }

        return new ModelAndView("/car/login");
    }
}
```

Use this filter [How to get session time out message using Spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708580/how-to-get-session-time-out-message-using-spring-security)

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)...in this request method

Comment: CAn you please provide me the full class with the additional code ? thanks

Comment: If you still don't understand,show me your login controller class..I will modify there itself

Comment: I don't have logincontroller. I got a loginSuccess.java and LoginFailure.java

Comment: Have you voted down to this answer?? may i know the reason??

Comment: which question? I'm am voting up

Comment: Write one controller which handles "/" request..as shown above