# How to Destroy Session If Someone leave Page | Spring Boot | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I am working on Fintech Application. We want to restrict User and INVALIDATE the session if **Back** button is used.

We are using AngularJs and Spring boot

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to create an API and call it when pressing back button, example:

```
@Controller
public class SessionController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/invalidate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void invalidate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803440/invalidate-session-spring-security)

Comment: How to track if someone press the back button. I am a fresh developer and have no idea about this

Comment: Add a listener on the back button, and call the above API to destroy the session.