# Class level request mapping @requestmapping execute some code on every request to that class

Tags: spring-mvc, session, request-mapping

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"user"})
public class UserController {
```

...

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"dashboard"})
public String index(HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap map) {
        this.objSession = req.getSession(false);
        try {
            System.out.println(this.objSession.getAttribute("userid"));
```

I am using Spring 4.2.
Suppose I have this class and I want to check the session object having the attribute userid=1 or not. 
I am doing this checking in every methods under this "/user" request.
My query is that if I can avoid this same coding which i am doing before executing any codes of any methods.

Is there any way round to increase code resuability for checking ?

In advance thanks for your time.

Comment: Use the filter [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36834942/4117061) and do a check for every request..

Comment: thanks @PrasannaKumar

Comment: is that worked?? if yes..i will mark this as duplicate..just you can upvote there..no need to answer and accept here

Comment: No, i tried it. Actually its not the case. I need to validate in each class i.e, on each RequestMapping. I need a solution by which I can validate some conditions per class level request mapping.

Comment: Class level?? You can map for particular requests Use `<mvc:interceptors path-matcher="/admin/**">` in spring-servlet xml

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `interceptors` by matching the request path.

```
<mvc:interceptors path-matcher="/someRequest/*">
    <bean class="className" autowire="constructor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

In `path-mathcer` you can specify one type of url,so that it will execute whatever you require.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"someRequest/user"})
public class UserController {
```

Interceptor: Before processing `someRequest/user` you can use a interceptor like below, in 3 ways you can use->`afterCompletion ,preHandle,postHandle`.

In you case code would be written in `preHandle` method

```
public class SomeRequestIntercept implements HandlerInterceptor  {

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object,
            Exception exception) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3)
            throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object arg2) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("before processing someRequest/**");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can u show me how to execute a method when request comes on a class level mapping?
Suppose a request comes like:
/user/something , 
/user/anotherthing, now I want a method to be executed both the times before it goes to the method mapped with "/something" and "/anotherthing" ??
Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: @subhajit is this helped??