# HTTP session invalidate redirect is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, httpsession

I am trying to redirect to logout url or send forbidden code in case of HTTP session time out. I can see from the logs that http session is getting timing out and destroyed.

But, it is not redirecting it to the logout page. Neither it is sending the FORBIDDEN code. It is not hitting that piece of code specified in invalidSessionStrategy.

The following is my config:

```
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .invalidSessionUrl(PropertyMgr.getXyzURL() + XyzConstants.LOGOUT_PAGE)
            .invalidSessionStrategy(new InvalidSessionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                     HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
                        throws IOException, ServletException {
                    logger.info("***************** Invalid session strategy called ***********************");
                    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);

                }
            })
            .and().addFilter(XyzSpringSecurityConfig.customExceptionTranslationFilter())
                .addFilterBefore(webServiceAuthenticationFilter(), XyzPreAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/services/**")
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CSRFRequestMatcher())
            .and()
                .addFilter(preAuthenticatedProcessingFilter())
                .authenticationProvider(XyzSpringSecurityConfig.preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/services/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(XyzSpringSecurityConfig.loginEntryPoint())
                .accessDeniedHandler(XyzSpringSecurityConfig.customAccessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/Logout"))
                .logoutUrl(PropertyMgr.getXyzURL() + XyzConstants.LOGOUT_PAGE)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
                .addFilterAfter(XyzSpringSecurityConfig.forceLogoutFilter(), XyzPreAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .invalidSessionUrl(PropertyMgr.getXyzURL() + XyzConstants.LOGOUT_PAGE)
                .invalidSessionStrategy(new InvalidSessionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
                            throws IOException, ServletException {
                        logger.info("*****************Invalid session strategy called ***********************");
                        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);

                    }
                })
            .and()
                .headers().xssProtection().disable();
```

Do I need to create filter for redirect during http session timeout ? Is it not possible with spring security ?

Comment: Apparently you are already messing around with the default logout behavior (which does what you want). You have an additional filter somewhere `XyzSpringSecurityConfig.forceLogoutFilter()` which judging by the name does something with logout as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708580/how-to-get-session-time-out-message-using-spring-security may be useful.

Comment: On another note your setup is really polluted, contains duplicate things (request mappings with security, rending one or the other useless. Also where do you login? Apparently you are using pre-authentication which basically means you are doing a new login if you don't have a session (if your credentials are still in the session).

Comment: Thanks Deinum ! >> Apparently you are using pre-authentication which basically means you are doing a new login if you don't have a session (if your credentials are still in the session). << That's exactly what's happening. I would like to avoid re-login and would like to redirect to the login page.